# I want to display one item per column in a table with a c# splitstring

Tags: c#

I display the data coming from an excel table and I separate them with a splitstring and I want each item to be displayed in cells separated horizontally rather than separated vertically

here is my code to display the data :

```
    private void btnExcelReader_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        long lastRow = excelRange.Rows.Count;
        long lastCol = excelRange.Columns.Count;

        int rowTotal = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < lastRow; i++)
        {
            if (excelRange.Cells[i, 1].Value2 != null)
            {
                rowTotal++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < rowTotal; i += 4)
        {
            char[] separator = new char[] { ' ' };
            string current = excelRange.Cells[i, 1].Value2;
            string[] splitCurrent = current.Split(separator,
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            for (int j = 0; j < splitCurrent.Length; j++)
            {
                lvName.Items.Add(splitCurrent[j]);
            }
        }
        lvName.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);
        lvName.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize);
    }
```

I try with columns.add, i create list and after that put my item in subitems.. nothing work.

Here is the image of the result in my ListView :
[image: ListView Result]

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but Excel has a TRANSPOSE function that does what you're after, I think. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/transpose-rotate-data-from-rows-to-columns-or-vice-versa-3419f2e3-beab-4318-aae5-d0f862209744

Comment: No, it's to send a string, which in a single row in my excel file, fragmented with a splitstring in c# then sent to my listview in my form. But thanks for the tips !